# Software that allows a Python application to display directed graphs in an interactive window?

Tags: python, gui, graphs, graphic-design

I have a Python application which can spit out a lot of data about points that relate to each other. I'd like to add a feature that would create a visual graph of that data such that a user could mouse over a point or edge on the graph and a little tool-tip window would appear and print out a brief description. I've included a screenshot of sort of what I'd like it to look like.

[image: Output of plot]

The colored columns represent points that are of the same category, and the arrows track directional relationships between the nodes.

One might obviously jump to a Python library to implement this feature, but I'm aware that other open-source tools like gnuplot exist and, perhaps, they may support creation of such a graph if given properly formatted data via stdin. I'm perfectly comfortable with that usage as well.

Could someone recommend a software or library that can create a plot like the above that adheres to the following requirements?

1. Can be used by a Python3 application - either via a Python3 library or through a more 'Unix-y' approach involving pipes.
2. Any files that need to be downloaded are available on Debian's main repository. If there's a **really good** library that's only available via pip then feel free to mention it, but preference will be given to something that I can manage with apt.

Comment: Have you tried python-networkx?

Comment: python-networkx looks really promising. I searched for a while, and there were a ton of libraries, but this one looks quite geared for my case. The only thing I don't explicitly see on their website is a description of how to make a tooltip appear by mousing over one of the points. Do you know if it has that feature?

Comment: It uses matplotlib for graphics, so, I believe, you should have a look at MPL's docs. Also, check out interactive nx_altair, pyvis, and plotly, if you haven't.

Comment: I just found a book regarding that. "Interactive Applications Using Matplotlib" by Benjamin V Root

Comment: And python-networkx appears to be available in Debian's repos as python3-networkx